# iOS swift 4 sets a default boolean to complicated static variables?

Tags: ios, swift, static, realm, xcode9.3

Hi I'm working on an app that is connected to a Web API and contains a local Database (Realm).
I have a **User** class which is a **Realm** `Object` subclass and keeps the user information such as `username`, `password`, `accessToken` and etc. It has also a **static variable and computed property** called `instance: User?` and `current: User?` Please find details below

```
class User: Object {

    /// Properties (Database Columns)
    @objc dynamic var username: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var password: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var accessToken: String = ""

    /// Current Logged In User
    static var current: User? {
        if instance == nil {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            instance = realm.objects(self).first
        }

        return instance
    }

    private static var instance: User?
}
```

As you can see `current` property returns the first `User` instance from realm database which is the logged in user information if there is any, otherwise it returns `nil`which means the user hasn't logged in the app.

I have also another class called **Configs** its name can describe what it does, there's a static boolean variable in it called `isLogin`. Here is the part of my code which I defined this

```
static var isLogin: Bool = User.current != nil
```

as you can see this property refers to `User.current` property described above and returns the result.
I call `Configs.isLogin` several times in the app whenever I want to check if the user is logged in or not so, I can tell the app to behave properly.
But when I call this property, it seems swift dive into the property and calls `User.current` **JUST ONCE** in an app session, the next times it just keeps the first result and assign it directly to `Configs.isLogin` and it will no more check the `User.current` property and won't runs query to see if there is any result or not, thus when for example the user fills and submits the registration form and gets a token from API and I save the information in Realm, if I call `Configs.isLogin` it still returns false since the first time in this session that it checked the `User.current` it was nil, but if I call `User.current` directly (after the registration) it's not nil anymore and I can access to the logged in user, also if I relaunch the app and start a new app session `Configs.isLogin` returns true which is correct and shows swift dives into the `User.current` and checked it and returned the proper result (as I mentioned at first of the article, only the first time it will dive into the class and checks the result).

I debugged my app several times and several parts until I found this problem, How can I make swift to always dive into `User.current` from `Config.isLogin` property when I call this config? is there something wrong with my code? and if yes what's the proper way? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `isLogin` is a variable initialized at first access. You can move the initialization part into a computed property so it always checks on User.current:

```
static var isLogin: Bool { return User.current != nil }
```

[Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) you can read up on Computed Properties.

Comment: It worked, I assumed it would always call the User.current as I'd written, but seems the variable keeps the result and I should've defined it as a computed property as you said, thank you